# Cropping scaled down images

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am not exactly sure how to describe the problem, so let me explain it with an example.

- Suppose I have a canvas setup with the width and height of 600x400.
- Now, I can chose an image (which can be of any dimension but usually bigger than 600x400) and draw it on the canvas.
- Now I need to crop the original image (suppose in this case it is 1000x500 px) to
  400x200 px.

How do I go about this to make sure I am cropping the original sized image while displaying the scaled down image on the canvas?

I am preferably looking at a completely client side solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/SEGZX/)**

Its actually very easy. All you need to do is draw the image to a canvas of the size you want, and call `toDataUrl()` on it afterwards to get the resulting image data. Drawing the image itself to a different canvas doesn't affect the output at all as long as you are drawing the contents of the original image to the cropped area.

```
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0],
    context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    img = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];

canvas.width = 600;
canvas.height = 400;

context.drawImage(img, 0,0,600,400);

var croppedCanvas = document.getElementById("tempCanvas"),
    croppedCtx = croppedCanvas.getContext("2d");

croppedCanvas.width = 400;
croppedCanvas.height = 200;

croppedCtx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
```

Comment: That works, thanks. btw, shouldn't it be croppedCtx.canvas.width =400;
croppedCtx.canvas.height = 200; ?

Comment: @redGREENblue ha good catch, I was working too fast I guess :P